# Unable To Contract Balance

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to check if my contract has any funds in it with a solidity function that works fine in remix.
The solidity func literally just returns this.balance(); which is all I really need.

```
function checkBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return this.balance;
}
```

I'm trying to call this function however programmatically in web3 and here's where I'm running into some trouble. I'm using the web3 func eth.getBalance to try and get the contract's current balance.

```
checkBalance: function() {
    App.contracts.HackathonDapp.deployed().then(function (instance) {
        return instance.checkBalance.call() 
    }).then(function (balance) {
        return web3.fromWei(web3.eth.getBalance('0xeec918d74c746167564401103096d45bbd494b74'));
    }).then (function (contractBalance) {
        console.log(contractBAlance);
    });
},
```

However, when I press the HTML button to call this function I get an error in my console:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a callback:

```
web3.eth.getBalance('...', function (err, result) { console.log(result); });
```

Comment: So that works but I'm getting one of those massive numbers in my console which exceeds javascript's capabilities `r {s: 1, e: 0, c: Array(1)}`, how would I get it to display a simple ether amount? Sorry i'm super beginner:p Thank you

Comment: What's returned is a `BigNumber`. Just call `.toString()` on it.